# UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill expands UIView's frame

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

Given that I have a `UIImage` that has some large frame.

I put this `UIImage` into a `UIImageView *myImageView;`

I set the content mode of myImageView to `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill`.

I also set the frame of myImageView to (50,50).

However, my `UIImage` is significantly bigger than this smaller frame, and for some reason, the image always expands myImageView's frame size.

How do I ensure that myImageView's frame stays constant and doesn't change from image to image?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure that actual frame is expanded or did you simply forget to set `myImageView.clipsToBounds` to `YES`? You can always check the frame with `NSLog (@"frame: %@", NSStringFromCGRect (myImageView.frame));`

Comment: That was exactly what I forgot!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Is one side of the image matching the desired dimension (50)? If it is, I suspect that your view is still the intended size, but it is not being clipped. Try setting `clipsToBounds` on your UIImageView to `YES`.

Answer (score -1):

I think your imageView Doesn't get expanded but image goes out of View bound, you can prevent that by adding this:

```
[yourImageView.layer setClipsToBounds:YES];
```